# R: Web Scraping Wikipedia's JavaScript Tables

Tags: javascript, r, web-scraping

I am trying to scrape all of the data in the table at: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_countries_by_firearm-related_death_rate

I have tried using selector gadget. I actually found the `Right-click -> Inspect` option in Chrome to be easier to use. I found the selector to be:

`#mw-content-text > div > table.wikitable.sortable.jquery-tablesorter`

However, I get the incorrect output, `character(0)`:

```
library(rvest)
url <- 'https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_countries_by_firearm-related_death_rate'
webpage <- read_html(url)
webpage %>%
        html_nodes("#mw-content-text > div > table.wikitable.sortable.jquery-tablesorter") %>% 
        html_text()
character(0)
```

I believe this is because the table is dynamically generated by Javascript, which `rvest` cannot read. I have heard that `RSelenium` can be used to download the html, which can then be parsed with my `rvest` code above. However, `RSelenium` looks like quite the rabbit hole (e.g. starting servers, Dockers, ports, etc.). Is there another, more intuitive and accessible option that I am unaware of or is RSelenium really my only option?

My goal is to write an RMarkdown report that will build a model with data scraped from one or more websites, hence my desire for an automatic web scraping solution.

Comment: Are you looking for a solution in R?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, this is an HTML table, not a Javascript table. When you inspect the page, you can see each table element, which you will not see if it's a Javascript table.

Using the table `xpath` works well here. You can copy it from the right-click menu when you Inspect the page.

```
require(rvest)
guns <- url %>% read_html() %>% html_nodes(xpath = '//*[@id="mw-content-text"]/div/table[3]') %>% 
  html_table()
guns <- guns[[1]]

                  Country Total Year   Homicides    Suicides Unintentional Undetermined       Sources and notes Guns per 100 inhabitants[citation needed]
1   Argentina ! Argentina  6.36 2009 2.58 (2012) 1.57 (2009)   0.05 (2009)  2.57 (2009) Guns in Argentina[1][2]                                      10.2
2   Australia ! Australia  0.93 2013 0.16 (2013) 0.74 (2013)   0.02 (2013)  0.02 (2013)    Guns in Australia[3]                                      21.7
3       Austria ! Austria  2.63 2011 0.10 (2011) 2.43 (2011)   0.01 (2009)  0.04 (2011)      Guns in Austria[4]                                      30.4
4 Azerbaijan ! Azerbaijan  0.30    ? 0.27 (2010) 0.01 (2007)   0.02 (2007)            ?   Guns in Azerbaijan[5]                                       3.5
5    Barbados !  Barbados  3.12    ? 3.12 (2013)           ?             ?            ?     Guns in Barbados[6]                                       7.8
6      Belarus !  Belarus  0.23    ? 0.14 (2009)           ?   0.09 (1996)            ?      Guns in Belarus[7]                                       7.3
```

Still some cleanup left to do, here's an example for country:

```
require(dplyr)
guns <- guns %>% mutate(Country = trimws(gsub("!.*","", Country)))
```

Comment: Thanks, very helpful. Yes, I used the same process as before and copied `xpath` instead, which returns the same results as you. Do you know why `xpath` works but `selector` doesn't? Seems like most blogs/tutorials suggest copying the `selector` via Inspect in Chrome or the Selector Gadget extension.

Comment: I don't know when you'd use `selector`, you could also use `html_nodes("table")[[3]]` though